# Attribute names for NWD files in Autodesk Forge viewer different from source Revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I search elements in the Forge viewer using a few parameters in the model that was translated from an NWD file, I find that the attribute names are different from the source Revit file.  For example, there is a parameter called "Assembly Name" in the source Revit file, but this name is changed to "LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_-1150420" in the model that was translated from the NWD file.

I found this out when I did a viewer.getProperties() and saw that for the "Assembly Name" parameter:

displayName = "Assembly Name"

attributeName = "LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_-1150420"

But the viewer.search() function uses the attributeName to perform the search in the model.  I have functions that search the model based on a few different parameters, so I have hardcoded these attributeNames to do the search.  But if there is a revised NWD and I need to upload it again to Forge, will these attributeNames change?  They look like some randomly generated string... Or is there some other method that can use the actual parameter name to do a search?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

All data extractor from the model should remain the same and authentic to the original model so long as the updates do not change them. Let us know if they change unexpectedly and send us the original model and relevant details to forge.help at autodesk.com.

It's the meta data/identifiers that are generated by our service for use of Viewer and other stacks that change each time the model is translated again and those include dbid(node ID) etc.