# For NWD file in Forge, the Viewer search method's attributeName parameter is different for different models?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an NWD file uploaded to Forge and it consists of several NWC files, each for a discipline (PL, ARC, FS etc). There is a custom parameter called "Asset_ID" in the models that I use to search for elements. However, when I check the properties of the elements using `viewer.getProperties` I found that the attributeName for my custom parameter is different for elements from different models:

Asset_ID in ARC - `attributeName = LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_2148458`

Asset_ID in PL - `attributeName = LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_1455561`

Asset_ID in FS - `attributeName = LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_2056618`

This creates a problem when I use the `viewer.search` function where I need to pass in the `attributeName` parameter to search for elements with specific Asset_ID - how do I know which `attributeName` value to pass in??  Is this a known issue?  Any workaround?

This is similar to the question I posted before:
[Attribute names for NWD files in Autodesk Forge viewer different from source Revit file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394560/attribute-names-for-nwd-files-in-autodesk-forge-viewer-different-from-source-rev). Difference is that for Revit built-in parameters, it seems that their `attributeName` are the same even for different models:

Mark - `attributeName = LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_-1001203`

Assembly Name - `attributeName = LcRevitData_Element:lcldrevit_parameter_-1150420`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service is usually trying to export the custom metadata "as faithfully as possible" but I'm guessing in this case it cannot assume that your *Asset_ID* attribute in one NWC file is the same as the *Asset_ID* attribute in another NWC file, and that's why they're getting custom suffixes when the NWC files are aggregated into a single viewer model.

If you wouldn't mind sharing your NWD sample with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, we'd be happy to pass it on to the Model Derivative engineering team and see if there's anything we can do to help.

Comment: I've emailed an NWD sample file. Thanks for the help!